# android studio Intent

Tags: android-intent, android-styles

I recently used Android Studio and I encountered the following problem. When I use an explicit Intent, everything is normal, but when I use an implicit Intent or other way, just like in the picture, the mobile phone simulator Stopped running, and I received the following error, I can't solve it. Every answer is helpful. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q88Q2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhHrK.png)

Comment: @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                显示Intent
//                Intent intent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
//                startActivity(intent);

//                隐式Intent
//                Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.lqs2.helloactivity.ACTION_START");
//                startActivity(intent);

                Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.shines.net.cn"));
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Please could you include the code sample in the question? I'm guessing that's what your comment is trying to do, but I really can't read it easily in one line :o)

Comment: @将克劳福德 i am sorry , emm, i am the new here , i haven't figure out how to upload a picture . i have solve the problem . Thank you very m much.